# PHP REST RewriteRule

Tags: php, apache, rest, mod-rewrite

I have a simple website/*.php files
I want to create a directory /api/webservice.php and i am having difficulties with what to do with the Apache set up. I have been through 10+ examples and still can get it working. My current setup is Virtual host file and i have added this into the config file. I have grabbed a number of solutions and tried to craft something. This is the last one and i am loosing the will even though i know the Rewrite condition is just wrong.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/posts.php
>     RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /api/$1 [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

All i want is a set of rules that will allow the normal website to function as the base directory. with the exception of anything sent to the path /api/client/create to be sent to the webservice.php api

Mod_rewrite is up and it is partially working when i just do /api it gose to the correct file but soon as its got additional bits on the end it fails.

Comment: Do you want to rewrite `/api/*` to `api/webservice.php` except `/api/client/create` ?

Comment: I already have a website fully developed at docroot and want to add in REST into a sub-directory in /apl called webservice.php the can take the propper REST syntax on PUT /apl/client or GET /api/client/3. Hope this makes sense. my new bit of Rewrite looks like this `    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ api.php?$1 [NC,L]
    </IfModule>`

Comment: That rewrite rule looks fine, so what's the problem ?

Comment: If i type url devbox.<domain>.co.uk/api/client/3 i get a 404 error. <br> if i type devbox.<domain>.co.uk/api/api.php it loads the file. The rules i have say anything that exists just display. Which makes sense why the api.php file opens. But the point of REST was to make a GET request for the first example and it be redirected to the api.php with the trailing path added to the $1 so i can then get at it within the API? If i am understanding REST then please let me know. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: In that case, your rewrite rule can be : `RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ api/api.php?$1 [NC,L]` ...

Comment: A direct call to the api.php works but when i use the REST call i get "The requested URL /api/client/3 was not found on this server." I had this rule set before and it made sense. But though i missed something.

Comment: I have included the httpd.conf lines `<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/<domain>.co.uk/httpdocs
    ServerName devbox.<domain>.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/devbox.<domain>.uk-error_log
    CustomLog logs/devbox.<domain>.co.uk-access_log common

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(api/.*)$ api/api.php?$1 [NC,L]

</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Try this : `RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/api.php?$1  [NC,L]`, there is a `/` before `api` ...

Comment: That got it :D its all working how I wanted, thanks for your help.

Comment: Final solution that works thanks to akmozo is '<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/<domain>.co.uk/httpdocs
    ServerName devbox.<domain>.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/devbox.<domain>.uk-error_log
    CustomLog logs/devbox.<domain>.co.uk-access_log common

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /api/api.php?$1 [NC,L]
</VirtualHost>' Just remember to set up your domain correctly. Thanks again :)